# Batch Update fails - Rollback operation

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I've created a PreparedStatement and have added a couple of data in a bactch

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.PreparedStatement("INSERT into table (a, b) values (?, ?)";

ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setInt(2, 2);

ps.addBatch

ps.setInt(1, 4);
ps.setInt(2, 5);

ps.addBatch
```

Now when I execute ps. I get the result, now lets say ps fails, then I want to insert the records, one by one not in the batch mode.

How do i extract the prepared statements, I can get the size, but not sure how to get the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not insert the records one by one in the first place? If your DBMS supports transactions - most modern ones do - you can bundle all your inserts into one atomic transaction and, to other users of the database, it'll look just like you added them all at once (see pseudocode below).

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
try{
    insert(1,2);
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("1, 2 didn't work");
}
try{
    insert(4,5);
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("4, 5 didn't work");
}
connection.commit();
```

Comment: Actually the requirement is so that if the batch update fails, then I need to insert the records one-by-one and capture the exception for that particular record.

Comment: You can still do that with this - just assign e to a variable and keep hold of it rather than printing a message (and do it in a loop, rather than writing everything sequentially). If you want to halt on the exception, just don't catch it inside your loop.

I'm not sure why you want to try the batch update first - you'll need to write code to do individual insertions anyway - why not use it in the first place?